# Как сделать эти функции в односвязном списке?

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

- Операция вставки - вставляет элемент в конкретную позицию в списке,
  перемещая элементы от этой позиции и дальше в следующую, более высокую позицию.
- Операция локализации - возвращает позицию объекта в списке. Если в списке
  объект встречается несколько раз, то возвращается позиция первого от начала
  список объекта. Если объекта нет в списке, то возвращается значение, равное
  длине списка, увеличенное на единицу.
- Операция выборки элемента списка - возвращает элемент, который
  находится в конкретной позиции списка. Результат не определен, если в
  списке нет такой позиции.
- Операция удаления - изымает элемент в конкретной позиции из списка.
  Результат не определен, если в списке нет указанной позиции.

  Операции выборки предыдущего и последующего элемента - возвращают
  соответственно следующей и предыдущей элемент списка отношении конкретного займу в
  списка

Сделал 1,3,4 но они не работающие а для других идей нет.

###Код###

```
        #include<iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Travelers
{
    int ticket_code;
    string lastname;
    int numberofthings;
    int luggage_weight;
    Travelers* Next;
};

Travelers* Head = 0;
struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
Date* Head2 = 0;
void Insert_Traveler(Travelers** list, Travelers* t, unsigned int pos)
{
    if (pos == 0 || *list == 0) { 
        t->Next = *list;   
        *list = t;
    }
    else if (pos == 0) {
        t->Next = *list;
        *list = t;
    }
    else {
        Travelers* p = *list;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
            if (i == pos - 1)
                break;
        t->Next = p->Next;
        p->Next = t;
    }
}
Travelers* Choose_Travelers(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos)
{
    while (list && pos)
    {
        list = list->Next;
        --pos;
    }

    return list;
}
Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore1(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos) {
    while (list && pos)
    {
        list = list->Next;
        --pos;
    }

    return Choose_Travelers(list, pos + 1);
}
Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore2(Travelers* list, unsigned int pos) {
    while (list && pos)
    {
        list = list->Next;
        --pos;
    }

    return Choose_Travelers(list, pos - 1);
}
int Location(Travelers* list, string key) {
    Travelers* p = list;
    unsigned int n = 0;
    for (; p; n++, p = p->Next) {
        if (p->lastname == key) break;
    }
    return n;
}
Travelers* Delete_Traveler(Travelers** list, unsigned int pos)
{
    Travelers* d = 0;

    if (pos == 0) {
        d = *list;
        *list = d->Next;
    }
    else {
        Travelers* p = *list;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
            if (i == pos - 1) {
                d = p->Next;
                p->Next = d->Next;
                break;
            }
    }

    return d;
}

void Print_Travelers(Travelers* list)
{
    for (Travelers* p = list; p; p = p->Next)
        cout << "code: " << p->ticket_code
        << "  " << p->lastname
        << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
        << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
        << '\n';
    cout << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char nm[10];
        Travelers* p = new Travelers;
        p->ticket_code = rand() % 1000;
        sprintf_s(nm, "tr_%d", i);
        p->lastname = nm;
        p->numberofthings = rand() % 5 + 1;
        p->luggage_weight = (rand() % 10 + 1) * p->numberofthings;

        Insert_Traveler(&Head, p, i);
    }

    cout << "list of travelers\n";
    Print_Travelers(Head);

    cout << "delete some travelers\n";
    Travelers* p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, 9);
    if (p) {
        cout << "delete as pos " << 9 << "  "
            << "code: " << p->ticket_code
            << "  " << p->lastname
            << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
        delete p;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, i);
        if (p) {
            cout << "delete as pos " << i << "  "
                << "code: " << p->ticket_code
                << "  " << p->lastname
                << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
                << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
                << '\n';
            delete p;
        }
    }

    cout << "------\n";
    cout << "\nlist of travelers after deletions\n";
    Print_Travelers(Head);
    int pos;
    cout << "Choose index" << endl;
    cin >> pos;
    Travelers* k = Choose_Travelers(Head, pos);
    if (!k)
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "code: " << k->ticket_code
            << "  " << k->lastname
            << " nth: " << k->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << k->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
    }
    cout << "Enter a key you want to choose" << endl;
    string key;
    cin >> key;
    int t = Location(Head, key);
    cout << t<<endl;
    int poss;
    cout << "Choose index" << endl;
    cin >> poss;
    Travelers* e = Choose_NextAndBefore1(Head, poss);
    if (!e)
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "code: " << e->ticket_code
            << "  " << e->lastname
            << " nth: " << e->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << e->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
    }
    Travelers* b = Choose_NextAndBefore2(Head, poss);
    if (!b)
        std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "code: " << b->ticket_code
            << "  " << b->lastname
            << " nth: " << b->numberofthings
            << " weight: " << b->luggage_weight
            << '\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: Поскольку у вас односвязный список, то для  вставки и удаления элемента в позиции `npos` вам нужен указатель на элемент в `npos -1`. Ищете его подсчитывание число шагов в цикле по `p = p->Next`. Далее меняете поле `Next` этого элемента. Естественно, для позиции 0 меняете `Head`. / Что касается операции локализации, то у вас не описано по каким полям искать элемент

Comment: это надо в цикле delete Travelers писать?

Comment: Для операции удаления там. Для вставки в `Insert_Element()` (кстати, пересмотрите список ее аргументов. Наверное лучше передавать в нее уже готовый к вставке элемент, т.е. `new` в ней не делать)

Comment: можете написать я что-то не понимаю как сделать вставку и удаление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите, как может быть сделана вставка

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Travelers
{
    int ticket_code;
    string lastname;
    int numberofthings;
    int luggage_weight;
    Travelers* Next;
};

Travelers* Head = 0;

void Insert_Traveler (Travelers **list, Travelers *t, unsigned int pos)
{
  if (pos == 0) {
    t->Next = *list;
    *list = t;
  } else {
    Travelers *p = *list;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
      if (i == pos - 1)
        break;
    t->Next = p->Next;
    p->Next = t;
  }
}

void Print_Travelers (Travelers *list)
{
  for (Travelers *p = list; p; p = p->Next)
    cout << "code: " << p->ticket_code
         << "  " << p->lastname
         << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
         << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
         << '\n';
  cout << '\n';
}

           

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char nm[10];
    sprintf(nm, "tr_%d", i);

    Travelers *p = new Travelers;
    p->ticket_code = random() % 1000;
    p->lastname = nm;
    p->numberofthings = random() % 5 + 1;    
    p->luggage_weight = (random() % 10 + 1) * p->numberofthings;

    Insert_Traveler(&Head, p, i);
  }

  Print_Travelers(Head);
}
```

Я думаю, с остальным вы справитесь сами (по аналогии).

**Update**

Удаление, imho, лучше сделать как вычеркивание  из списка. Удалять ранее выделенный объект можно в вызывающем коде.

```
Travelers * Delete_Traveler (Travelers **list, unsigned int pos)
{
  Travelers *d = 0;
  
  if (pos == 0) {
    d = *list;
    *list = d->Next;
  } else {
    Travelers *p = *list;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
      if (i == pos - 1) {
        d = p->Next;
        p->Next = d->Next;
        break;
      }
  }

  return d;
}
```

Обратите внимане, после удаления элемента из списка, позиции всех следующих элементов уменьшатся на 1.

Проверить можно вот таким кодом в main.

```
  Print_Travelers(Head);

  Travelers *p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, 9);
  if (p) {
    cout << "delete as pos " << 9 << "  "
         << "code: " << p->ticket_code
         << "  " << p->lastname
         << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
         << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
         << '\n';
    delete p;
  }

      
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, i);
    if (p) {
      cout << "delete as pos " << i << "  "
           << "code: " << p->ticket_code
           << "  " << p->lastname
           << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
           << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
           << '\n';
      delete p;
    }
  }

  cout << "------\n";
  Print_Travelers(Head);
```

Надеюсь, теперь вам уже понятно, как программировать оставшиеся пункты вашего задания.

---

**Update 2**

Запустите вот этот код

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


struct Travelers
{
    int ticket_code;
    string lastname;
    int numberofthings;
    int luggage_weight;
    Travelers* Next;
};

Travelers* Head = 0;

void Insert_Traveler (Travelers **list, Travelers *t, unsigned int pos)
{
  if (pos == 0) {
    t->Next = *list;
    *list = t;
  } else {
    Travelers *p = *list;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
      if (i == pos - 1)
    break;
    t->Next = p->Next;
    p->Next = t;
  }
}

Travelers * Delete_Traveler (Travelers **list, unsigned int pos)
{
  Travelers *d = 0;
  
  if (pos == 0) {
    d = *list;
    *list = d->Next;
  } else {
    Travelers *p = *list;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; p->Next; i++, p = p->Next)
      if (i == pos - 1) {
    d = p->Next;
    p->Next = d->Next;
    break;
      }
  }

  return d;
}

void Print_Travelers (Travelers *list)
{
  for (Travelers *p = list; p; p = p->Next)
    cout << "code: " << p->ticket_code
     << "  " << p->lastname
     << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
     << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
     << '\n';
  cout << '\n';
}

       

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    char nm[10];
    Travelers *p = new Travelers;
    p->ticket_code = random() % 1000;
    sprintf(nm, "tr_%d", i);
    p->lastname = nm;
    p->numberofthings = random() % 5 + 1;    
    p->luggage_weight = (random() % 10 + 1) * p->numberofthings;

    Insert_Traveler(&Head, p, i);
  }

  cout << "list of travelers\n";
  Print_Travelers(Head);

  cout << "delete some travelers\n";
  Travelers *p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, 9);
  if (p) {
    cout << "delete as pos " << 9 << "  "
     << "code: " << p->ticket_code
     << "  " << p->lastname
     << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
     << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
     << '\n';
    delete p;
  }

      
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p = Delete_Traveler(&Head, i);
    if (p) {
      cout << "delete as pos " << i << "  "
       << "code: " << p->ticket_code
       << "  " << p->lastname
       << " nth: " << p->numberofthings
       << " weight: " << p->luggage_weight
       << '\n';
      delete p;
    }
  }

  cout << "------\n";
  cout << "\nlist of travelers after deletions\n";
  Print_Travelers(Head);  
}

avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ g++ -Wall -O2 ttt.cpp
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
list of travelers
code: 383  tr_0 nth: 2 weight: 16
code: 915  tr_1 nth: 4 weight: 24
code: 386  tr_2 nth: 3 weight: 30
code: 421  tr_3 nth: 3 weight: 24
code: 690  tr_4 nth: 5 weight: 20
code: 926  tr_5 nth: 1 weight: 7
code: 172  tr_6 nth: 2 weight: 4
code: 368  tr_7 nth: 3 weight: 30
code: 782  tr_8 nth: 1 weight: 3
code: 123  tr_9 nth: 3 weight: 18

delete some travelers
delete as pos 9  code: 123  tr_9 nth: 3 weight: 18
delete as pos 0  code: 383  tr_0 nth: 2 weight: 16
delete as pos 1  code: 386  tr_2 nth: 3 weight: 30
delete as pos 2  code: 690  tr_4 nth: 5 weight: 20
delete as pos 3  code: 172  tr_6 nth: 2 weight: 4
delete as pos 4  code: 782  tr_8 nth: 1 weight: 3
------

list of travelers after deletions
code: 915  tr_1 nth: 4 weight: 24
code: 421  tr_3 nth: 3 weight: 24
code: 926  tr_5 nth: 1 weight: 7
code: 368  tr_7 nth: 3 weight: 30

avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

По крайней мере у меня он работает.

Comment: я сделал удаления но чего-то не работает, обновил

Comment: @vasiligor, вы слишком буквально восприняли "по аналогии". Ок, я добавлю в обновлении ответа код для удаления.

Comment: чего-то не работает сразу программа завершается и можете подсказать как сделать операцию локализации и Операция выборки элемента списка?

Comment: @vasiligor, не работает мой код? Попробуйте вставить update а конец и запустите.

Comment: обновил, но что-то не работает

Comment: Запустите код из **update 2**, что вы видите?

Comment: спасибо, можете подсказать как еще сделать те 3 операции?

Comment: я что-то не очень понимаю как

Comment: Попробуйте все же сами. Например, "Операция выборки элемента списка" -- это просто цикл  `p = p->Next;` N раз по списку. Возвращаете этот указатель.

Comment: можете посмотреть на функцию ChooseElement это Операция выборки элемента списка

Comment: Нет, это  неверно. Функция должна получать голову списка и позицию. Она должна **возвращать** указатель. Код -- что-то такое `Travelers *p = list;   for (unsigned int n = 0; p; n++, p = p->Next) if (n == pos)  break;   return p;`

Comment: можете посмотреть почему не выводить элемент?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду `int voidChoose(Travelers** list, Travelers* t, unsigned int pos)`, то **не нужно передавать туда адрес заголовка списка и никак не используемый указатель `t`**, а     надо -- `Travelers* voidChoose(Travelers* list,  unsigned int pos) { Travelers* p = list;  
    for (unsigned int n = 0; p; n++, p = p->Next) {
        if (n == pos)
            break;
    } 
     return p; }`

Comment: ее тогда вот так вызывать? `voidChoose(Head,pos);`

Comment: Да, только результат надо получать. `Travelers *t = voidChoose(Head,pos);` / Ну, и наверное voidCoose надо на что-то более подходящее заменить, скажем, `Choose_Traveler`

Comment: чего-то не выводит, обновил

Comment: @vasiligor, не спеша попрограммируйте сами. Попечатайте переменные по ходу выполнения или отладчиком воспользуйтесь

Comment: еще бы узнать как сделать те 2 операции Операция локализации,Операции выборки предыдущего и последующего элемента

Comment: Подумайте сами, пофантазируйте, сделайте свои варианты

Comment: добавил те две операции можете посмотреть, но чего выдает ошибки

Comment: Принципиально неправильно. `return p + 1;
    return p - 1;` ???  Вообще, там надо 2 функции -- одна для предыдущего, а другая для следующего (но если хоть чуть-чуть подумать (это к тому, кто дал задание), то такая функция не нужна) / И в location как тут -- `if (p == key)` (вы компилировать-то пробовали?), так и `return list;` Зачем вы возвращаете первый элемент списка? Надо не первый, а найденный, т.е. `p`

Comment: `if (p == key)` а как тогда сравнивать?

Comment: Смотрите, `p` это указатель на структуру с кучей полей. Вы хотите, чтобы **компилятор догодался** какое из них вы имели в виду. Я конечно понимаю, что очень жалко, но такой уровень интеллекта (или телепатию) в компилятор встроить не удалось. Т.о. укажите это ему сами.

Comment: это не будет такое же как Операция выборки элемента списка?

Comment: Не понял. `"это не будет такое же как..."` -- **это**, это что вы имели в виду?

Comment: `if (p == key)` ну чтобы сравнить п по индексу а не по слову так? как тогда этот стринг превратить в индекс?

Comment: Нет, все проще. С каким полем в структуре `Travelers` вы хотели сравнить `key`? Я думаю (конечно же, методом исключения), что с `lastname`. Вот и сравнивайте. Потом все оттранслируйте и протестируйте. Запимните, когда тестируете вы должны заранее знать, какой вывод программы хотите увидеть для заданных исходных данных. Успехов!

Comment: я думал что нужно написать название поля в структуре и чтобы программа выдала его индекс

Comment: . Эта функция возвращает позицию объекта х в списке L

Comment: Да, я почему-то подумал, что нужно выдать сразу структуру. Если индекс, то да, тогда получаем `int Location(Travelers* list, string key) {... }` Считаете в цикле число шагов  и  `if (p->lastname == key) return n;` Не забудьте, что если не найден, то в конце надо выдать новый индекс. Это будет `n + 1`. Поэтому `n` надо объявить до `for (...)`

Comment: можете посмотреть хорошо сделал те 2 операции

Comment: `else return -1;` это неправильно. Если первый же не равен, то вернете -1. И `unsigned int n;`  вынести из `for (...)` забыли. Опять же, `return n;` в конце функции (уже после `for (..)`) нет

Comment: `int Location(Travelers* list, string key){`
    `Travelers* p = list;`
   ` unsigned int n = 0;`
    `for (n,p; n++, p = p->Next) {
       ` if (p->lastname == key) {
        }`
        `return n;`
    }
    return -1;
}

Comment: как-то так?????

Comment: Да, только в конце `return n;`, а не -1 (и for можно записать так `for (; p; n++, p = p->Next) {`  т.е. без пустых выражений `n, p` в его начале)

Comment: как вставить и удалить элемент который пропишет пользователь?(обновил код)

Comment: Посмотрел внимательно. В Insert_Traveler моя недоработка, не предусмотрено, что в пустой список первый элемент записывают с позиции отличной от 0. Исправляется добавление проверки, что список пуст в первой строке. Получим -- `if (pos == 0 || *list == 0) {
    t->Next = *list;
    *list = t;
  } else { ....` / Ну, вторая ошибочка, что вы в Location() внутри `if (p->lastname == key) {
        }` забыли **`break;`**

Comment: Вообще-то, я бы вам посоветовал со всем этим уже правленным кодом и новыми ошибками задавать новые вопросы в отдельных темах (а то при таком режиме работы, как мы с вами тут развели модераторы нас быстро прихлопнут. Тут (на сайте) в общем-то действует правило -- не вести дискуссий, работать в плане один вопрос -- ответы разных юзеров на него)

Comment: Почему не работает функция для операция локализации---int Location,Функция для операция выборки элемента списка----Travelers* Choose_Travelers,и функция для операции операции выборки предыдущего и последующего элемента(2 функции Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore1 и Travelers* Choose_NextAndBefore2)

Comment: задал вопрос сразу -2 получил

Comment: Вы break в Location вставили? Если вставите, будет работать. Choose_Travelers должна работать, наверное что-то не то передаете ей. В обеих функциях выборки  вот такой `return p + 1;` это абсолютно не то, что надо. В них я вообще не понял, что имеется в виду под `"конкретного займу в списка"`

Comment: то есть при введенном индекса следующий и предыдущий элемент

Comment: @vasiligor, если следующий/предыдущий от заданного индекса, то это же элементарно `return Choose_Travelers(list, pos  + 1)`  для следующего и `return Choose_Travelers(list, pos  -  1)` для предыдущего

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а в самом деле для чего ему минусы? Чтобы потешить свое самомнение?

Comment: почему всегда функция location выдает 4 я уже все tr_ писал

Comment: @vasiligor, тот код, что в тексте вопроса точно совпадает с тем, что вы запускаете? Я сейчас оттранслирую его и попробую сам

Comment: на всякий случай обновил

Comment: Попробовал.  `Choose_Travelers()`   работает со всеми индексами; `Location()` работает со всеми tr_N; В обеих `Choose_NextAndBefore()` надо выбросить циклы (зачем они там?) и оставить только return-ы. Наверное вы или пробуете не тот код или что-то не то вводите с клавиатуры.

Comment: спасибо, можете еще помочь как в список добавить список date чтобы был один список через функцию?

Comment: Не понял. Что мешает просто добавить date к полям структуры  Travelers?

Comment: там просто так звучит задание написать программу для объединения
двух списков в один.

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду свою структуру `struct Date {...}`, то в существующем виде она не годится под элемент списка. Более того, обычно все элементы списка это структуры одного типа. Поэтому я не понимаю этот пункт вашего задания. Уточните и если не справитесь сами, то задайте отдельным вопросом. / Что же касается объединения 2-х списков из одинаковых структур в один, то это очень просто. В поле next последнего элемента одного списка записываете указатель из заголовка второго списка.

Comment: можете написать?

Comment: @vasiligor, если сами не начнете писать и отлаживать, толку все равно не будет. Попробуйте. Придумайте в конце-концов маленький пример. Напишите код. При запусках печатайте промежуточные значения переменных и думайте, почему они отличаются от ожидаемых. Если не понимаете, выдвигайте разные гипотезы и проверяйте их (печатью переменных (или научитесь пользоваться отладчиком)). /  Если совсем не будет получаться, тогда задавайте вопрос, выкладывая в т.ч. отладочный вывод в консоль.

Comment: можно что-то типа такого но тогда должны быть 2 структуры? `void Unite_Travelers(Travelers* head1, Travelers* head2)
{
    Travelers* p = head1;
    while (p->Next != NULL)
        p = p->Next;
    p->Next = head2;
}`

Comment: Да, похоже. Только проверьте сами на компьютере

Comment: вызвал функцию  Unite_Travelers(Head, Head2); затем сделал вывод Print_Travelers(Head);но чего-то получается бесконечный цикл

Comment: Наверное у вас Head2 это указатель на один из элементов списка Head1. Так нельзя. Это д.б. два независимых списка

Comment: ой там должно быть (Head,Head) но все равно бесконечный цикл

Comment: Сделайте 2 независимых списка и вызовите с ними свою функцию

Comment: все поля должны быть такими же?

Comment: Заполните их чем-нибудь разным, чтобы на выводе отличать одни элементы от других

Comment: спасибо, можете подсказать как отсортировать список по любому ключу?

Comment: Задавайте новые вопросы в основном сайте. Я здесь больше отвечать не буду.

Comment: задал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263320/как-отсортировать-список-по-любому-ключу

Comment: Прочтите хотя-бы [этот раздел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) в справке по сайту. Кстати, вы ее вообще-то смотрели?